# How can I make border for dot (CSS)

Tags: css, border

How can I make border for dot as on the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to make it, here's one:

```css
.dot {
  color: steelblue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: solid 1px currentColor;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.dot.on {
  background-color: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<i class="dot"></i>
<br />
<i class="dot on"></i>
```